# Geocode and tweets in searchTwitter with TwitteR (r package)

Tags: r, twitter

When searching for tweets in the UK, I specified the geocode option :

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("british", n=100,
                        lang="en",since="2016-06-22", until="2016-06-24",
                        geocode='54.20,-2,700km')
```

However, in the resultats, the values of longitude and latitude are `NA`. (Only very few of them have values). Does that mean that twitter hides the results ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that means users are not sharing their specific coordinates when posting tweets, but the users still fit the geo parameters based on their profile coordinates.

According to the API documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), the search tweets requests identified geo restrictions by available lay/long and then by profile location when that's not available.

Comment: Is it possible to get the coordinates of the user ?